# Why don't the absolute value methods on signed integers return unsigned values?

Tags: rust

The following code fails to compile:

```
fn main() {
    let x = (-5i32).abs();

    let z: u32 = x;
}
```

with the message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     let z: u32 = x;
  |                  ^ expected u32, found i32
```

Reading [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.abs), it looks the choice of `i32` stems from the fact that `i32::min_value()` has no positive representation in `i32`. However, it *would* have a positive representation in `u32`, which can represent numbers twice as large.

I'm learning the language, and want to understand why certain design decisions were made so that I can develop good habits. I find this one confusing. Can someone explain why it works this way instead of just returning a `u32`, which would seem to be the semantically correct type?

Comment: Consider this snippet (I assume it would likely be valid Rust): `let x = -5i32; x = x.abs();` returning u32 would require a cast to assign it back to the same variable, which is one reason I'd imagine its generally implemented the way it is

Comment: @Thymine That's true. The pull request Shepmaster links has a discussion that argues this is emperically a much rarer usecase than trying to work with the result as an unsigned number though. It also has the development minutes, so I'm writing up an answer based on those.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a link to [the development meeting minutes](https://github.com/rust-lang/meeting-minutes/blob/master/weekly-meetings/2015-04-07.md#change-abs-to-return-unsigned) where this was discussed in the [proposed RFC "Change abs() to return unsigned integers"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1017)

It looks like the main reasons were:

1. Many other languages use `i32` -> `i32` (for instance, C, Java), because the accidental promotion of other values to `u32` might cause bugs. Rust seems to have used `i32` -> `i32` for this reason originally (i.e. following convention), but doesn't suffer from the same kinds of bugs.
2. This feature request wasn't submitted until after Rust had reached beta. The developers were not willing to introduce a breaking change to the language over what appears to be a rare bug. This looks like the main reason offered for keeping things this way.

It seems like the accepted workaround is to use `as u32` to cast.

`i32::overflowing_abs` `i32::wrapping_abs` and `i32::checked_abs` implement other solutions to the `i32::min_value()` bug, but none of them produces a u32.

Comment: Nice tidbit of Rust archaeology!