# Is there a way to get the u32 absolute value of an i32 that does the correct thing for std::i32::MIN?

Tags: rust

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753297/why-dont-the-absolute-value-methods-on-signed-integers-return-unsigned-values) and its answer describe why abs() on an i32 returns an i32 rather than a u32. It says "it seems like the accepted workaround is to use `as u32` to cast". However, that will panic in debug mode if the argument is `std::i32::MIN`. Is there a way in the standard library to get the correct value, or should I write my own implementation with a special case for this value - something like this:

```
fn my_abs(x: i32) -> u32 {
  if x == std::i32::MIN {
    (-(x as i64)) as u32
  } else {
    x.abs() as u32
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I just realized that `x.wrapping_abs() as u32` does what I want: all numbers other than `std::i32::MIN` are mapped to their absolute value as an i32 first, then cast to u32, and `std::i32::MIN` stays the same but then casting it to u32 happens to turn it into its absolute value. This works for other bit widths too.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I stumbled across it while looking for the same answer. From Rust version 1.51.0, there is an `unsigned_abs` method on i32 (https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.unsigned_abs)